# invalid tags in HTML <abc> vs <1234>

Tags: html, web

I was writing a simple web page. And I wanted to print `<abc>` and `<1234>` inside the page. Why `<1234>` is printed not `<abc>`? I know `<abc>` is invalid tag thats why it is not rendered. But what about `<1234>`?

Answer (score 3):

This is down to the way that browsers parse the HTML into a format that gets displayed as a web page.

As a rule, HTML tags must start with letters. Because of this, the browser attempts to parse  as a valid tag (therefore hiding it), but doesn't recognise <1234> and therefore leaves it untouched.

Edit:

As @Arkana pointed out below, there's nothing I can see in the HTML specification that specifically forbids starting a HTML tag with a number. My best guess is that because [no (currently valid) HTML tags actually do start with a number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html#html-elements), the browser's parser just ignores these tags, based on the same rule that [IDs and Names follow](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html) according to the HTML4 spec.

Comment: That's what I thinked at first time, but the specification doesn't seems to say anything concrete: [Tag names are used within element start tags and end tags to give the element’s name. HTML elements all have names that only use characters in the range 0–9, a–z, and A–Z.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#tag-name). Please, can you show a link with the info of where this is defined?

Comment: @Arkana, the document that you quote “has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes”. The actual HTML specifications define the syntax normatively.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like:

```
and &lt;1234&gt;
```

Use HTML entities.

```
&lt; = <
&gt; = >
```

Using them tells HTML that you want the `<` and `>` to be displayed as it is and not be interpreted as the `<` and `>` in `<html>`

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PW8YW/)

P.S.: [Here's a list of them.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 1):

In XHTML and in HTML5 (even in HTML serialization), both `<abc>` and `<123>` are invalid. In HTML 4.01, `<123>` is valid, though not recommended, and it simply means those five data characters.

What matters in browsers is how they parse an HTML document. There is an attempted semi-formal description of this in HTML5 CR, but it’s a bit hard reading. The bottom line is that `<` triggers special parsing: if the next character is a letter, data is parsed as an HTML tag; otherwise, the `<` as well as data after it are taken as normal data characters.

When a tag like `<abc>` has been parsed, modern browsers construct an element node in the document tree – even though the tag is invalid and the tag name is not known to the browser at all. If there is no end tag `<abc>`, the node contains all the rest there is in the document. But for an element node with an unknown name, there is no default styling and no default action. You won’t notice its existence, unless you try to do something with it (like put `abc { color: solid red }` in a style sheet).

Technically, one could say that the cause of the difference is that “a” is a name start character (a character that may appear as the first one in a tag name), whereas “1” is not.

It is safest to always escape a “<” character in content (except for `style` and `script` and `xmp` elements, which have rules of their own) as `&lt;`. There is no need to escape a “>”, but if desired, for symmetry, you can escape it as `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Unrecognised elements are added to the DOM for forward compatibility (they can be enhanced with CSS/JS). Element names may not begin with a number though, so they are not added to the DOM and error recovery treats them as text instead.

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` if you want to include `<` and `>` as data instead of markup.